# How to retrive and show the records of given date range in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I want to select the date range using jquery datepicker and retrive records of that date range and show them in report. I want the jquery datepicker values to be passed to the query in my controller.

My form (dateFilter.html.erb)for datepicker values is as below:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'expenses', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :class =>"datepicker") do %>
<%= label_tag("Start Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:start_date) %>
<%= label_tag("End Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:end_date) %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

expenses_controller is as below :

```
 def dateFilter  
   @expenses = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]))  
 end
```

Here is application.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#start_date").datepicker();
   $("#end_date").datepicker();

});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work with two small changes:

Change your query to convert the params to dates:

```
where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date .. params[:end_date].to_date))
```

And make sure you have set up the datepicker to use a format that `#to_date` understands. E.g.:

```
$(...).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"})
```